# How to use the result of a query like parameters of another one ?? ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a query that returns this

```
SELECT COLNAME FROM TABLE_1 WHERE CATALOG_ID = 40;

    COLNAME
    ----------------
    CONVERTED_VALUE
    CONVERTED_VALUE_01
    CONVERTED_VALUE_02
    CONVERTED_VALUE_03
    VALUE_DESCRIPTION
```

I need to convert this result into a query like the next:

```
SELECT CONVERTED_VALUE, CONVERTED_VALUE_01, CONVERTED_VALUE_02, 
CONVERTED_VALUE_03 , VALUE_DESCRIPTION 
FROM TABLE2 WHERE CATALOG_ID = 40;
```

Is posible to do this in a single query I don't know for example

```
SELECT( SELECT COLNAME FROM TABLE_1 WHERE CATALOG_ID = 40 ) 
FROM TABLE_2 WHERE CATALOG_ID = 40;
```

Obviously that doesn't work but is the idea :)

I really don't know how to achieve this. Any suggestion guys? I'm not an expert at using databases :(

I'm using Oracle 10.

The idea is basically convert the result of the first query into the parameters of the second one.

Comment: Nice try, but no, this will not work. The number, name and order of columns in a SELECT statement must be literals, they can't be expressions that resolve to strings. (So: column names cannot be bind variables, they can't be values stored in a table - as in your case, they can't be the result of applying string operations, etc.) What you are doing right now is close to the best you can expect - it's a "manual" form of dynamic SQL, which is what your overall problem requires.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for, as long as my understanding of your question is correct:

```
SELECT
  t.CONVERTED_VALUE,
  t.CONVERTED_VALUE_01,
  t.CONVERTED_VALUE_02, 
  t.CONVERTED_VALUE_03,
  t.VALUE_DESCRIPTION
FROM
  (SELECT COLNAME FROM TABLE_1 WHERE CATALOG_ID = 40) t,
  TABLE_2
WHERE TABLE_2.CATALOG_ID = 40;
```

If i'm not understanding what you're asking let me know.

Comment: Hello thanks for your time and atention, let's see the first query can return diferent values, for example just the value CONVERTED_VALUE and VALUE_DESCRIPTION, and the second one must take that result to make a new query.

Answer (score 0):

This is what came to my mind. But firing select statement from anonymous block would not look nice.

```
DECLARE
    V_COL VARCHAR2(100):='';
    s_ql VARCHAR2(200):='';
BEGIN
    SELECT LISTAGG(COLNAME,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY COLNAME) AS COL INTO V_COL FROM TABLE_1 WHERE CATALOG_ID = 40 group by CATALOG_ID;
    s_ql:='SELECT '||V_COL||' FROM TABLE2 WHERE CATALOG_ID = 40';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (s_ql);
END
```

You can use some variable or collection to capture result and display it using **DBMS_OUTPUT** .

Answer (score 0):

the return format of select statement does not match the column name format we need to provide, so it's not possible i guess :(

Comment: But you can do it using cursors in PLSQL, but not possible in only SQL.